# C# Not Recognizing SafeTokenHandle

Tags: c#, windows, permissions

I have a compilation error with C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true,CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool ***LogonUser***(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword,
int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out ***SafeTokenHandle*** phToken);
```

In the word at the * sign (LogonUser and SafeTokenHandle). My C# compiler can not compile because of unknown type.
I develop with visual studio 2012, windows 64, framework 4.0.

Please Help.

Comment: Thank you for edit my wording.My English not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because these struct aren't defined in your project.

from what i know you neet the method to be:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool LogonUser(
   string lpszUsername,
   string lpszDomain,
   string lpszPassword,
   int dwLogonType,
   int dwLogonProvider,
   out IntPtr phToken
);
```

[here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.logonuser) is an explanation on the function

Comment: This solution and your explanation can be used.

Answer (score 11):

`SafeTokenHandle` is not part of the .Net framework. I'm assuming your code is somewhat related to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w070t6ka.aspx), So you're missing the definition:

```
public sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    private SafeTokenHandle()
        : base(true)
    {
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return CloseHandle(handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. But Visual Studio unknow [SupperssUnmanagedCodeSecurity].

Comment: You need to add `using System.Security;` to have that. Generally you can do ctrl+. to resolve such issues (or using the right click menu), or even search Google for the type name to find it's namespace and assembly.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but what is actually happening in the SafeTokenHandle class above?